# Migrate SQL Server data from one database to another

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, data-migration

We have 2 servers with a database containing the same tables and structures but different data. One is the testing environment, the other one contains productive data.

We want to copy the data from the productive database to the testing database. What is the best approach to achieve this?

If I delete the data first; will I be able to insert the data? Or will the primary key's count from where they were? What about inserting the primary keys for tables that have autonumbering?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use a specialized tool for this, like [Red Gate Software's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) which allows you to "diff" and "sync" two database tables in a visual manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your specific need and data structure but here are some options to think over (prioritised in terms of what I would recommend):-

- A simple backup and restore will be the easiest and quickest solution;
- Using a data scripting tool (like [Red-Gate's Data Compare](http://red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)) could solve your needs;
- A SSIS package could be developed to pump data back and forth between the two instances; or
- Write your own script using the `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON / OFF` command for the identity seeded tables

Comment: I will have a look at Red-Gate, Thank you